# Datatables ajax sort by method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables, will-paginate

I have a basic datatables that I use with will_paginate.

```
<table id="users" class="display" data-source="<%= url_for(:controller => "/account", :action => :paginate, :format => :json) %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
      return $('#users').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: $('#users').data('source'),
        columns : [
            { data: "first_name" },
            { data: "last_name" },
            { data: "username" },
            { data: "role" }
        ]
      });
    });
</script>
```

While everything mostly work wonderfully, including the column search, my role column, however, does not.

While everything else are attributes that I use SQL to query, role is a method call.

```
def role
  return "admin" if self.admin?
  return "manager" if self.manager?
  return "user"
end
```

This in turn will not work with column sorting.

With that said, is there a way to use will_paginate and datatables with ajax to use a custom sort with the method output? I tried using `data-order` on the column but that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using will-paginate for while but I stopped using it. Try to use [datatables](https://datatables.net/) only without pagination as it has a pagination inside.

Here is the code example

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        // DO NOT REMOVE : GLOBAL FUNCTIONS!
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var responsiveHelper_dt_basic = undefined;
                var responsiveHelper_dt_basic2 = undefined; 
                var breakpointDefinition = {
                    tablet : 1024,
                    phone : 480
                };
                $('#users_table').dataTable({
                    "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'l>r>"+
                        "t"+
                        "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
                    "autoWidth" : true,
                    "preDrawCallback" : function() {
                        // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
                        if (!responsiveHelper_dt_basic) {
                            responsiveHelper_dt_basic = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#users_table'), breakpointDefinition);
                        }
                    },
                    "rowCallback" : function(nRow) {
                        responsiveHelper_dt_basic.createExpandIcon(nRow);
                    },
                    "drawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
                        responsiveHelper_dt_basic.respond();
                    },
                    "iDisplayLength": 50
                });                     
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Without server side pagination, datatable with records greater than 1000 is incredibly slow though...

Comment: There are different methods to decrease the response time like find in batch or making a view with the data and calculation you need to view. please see this article about database views in rails https://melsatar.blog/2017/05/27/database-views-for-rails-performance-optimization/

Comment: The issue isn't server side, datatables is extremely memory intensive client side. I can generate 10,000 records in less than 2 seconds, but it'll take upwards of 30 seconds for the client to attach the datatable elements on it.

Comment: Okay, I tested that with more than 3000 records in one page with listing a lot of relations and it had an acceptable response time without views even and more information presented as well. I agree with you that it will be an issue if you have timeout error to load the data at the client side.